# Unable to Run remote system commands via applet

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

I want to execute windows/linux commands on command line via Applet.But unable to do so and get FileIOException (Unable to access remote system). Even I have signed applet with jarsigner tool.

Below given code is to kill/stop running Skype application -

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
public class App extends Applet
{

 public void init()
 {
 AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
                public Object run() {
                try
                {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Taskkill /IM Skype.exe");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Caught exception in privileged block, Exception:" + e.toString());
                }
                return null;


}});
```

}
}

But when I run similar code with web start technology then I Skype application running in Windows OS system stops.In Java web start we required JRE to be installed on remote system i.e. very lengthy process& user have to face security problems.  Kindly provide suggestion which technology to follow (I would prefer Applet due to less hectic job) and how to implement this in Applet

Comment: *"(I would prefer Applet due to less hectic job)"*  You apparently don't understand applets...  Look over the [tag:applet] questions over the last 48 hours for a hint (and that is just a drop in the ocean of 'applet madness').

Comment: I agree with your "drop in the ocean of applet madness" comment.But In java web start on other hands, user has to download JRE and install it which is quite time consuming .Is there another way?

Comment: *"But In java web start on other hands, user has to download JRE and install it"*  You are mistaken in believing an applet can work **without** a JRE.  Oracle supplies the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to ensure there is a suitable minimum version of the plug-in available to run either *Java Web Start apps. **or applets.***  The script makes it a very simple task for the user.

Comment: JNLP file can be run only via javaws (installed on system) i.e it rely on System JRE. Where as applets need only java plugin on browser(provided by every browser).Applets doesn't depend upon system's JRE

Comment: You are so mistaken it is hard to know where to begin.  But I will start with, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/topusers) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers)...  (I am not just 'plucking this information out of the air'.)

Comment: Sir how can I resolve problem of security. Even I signed jar file launched by jnlp via jarsigner tool. But still i have to change security settings in javacpl.exe to run jar on browser blocked by security. Kindly provide solution for this.

Comment: Did you *actually read* the applet question in the last 48 hours like I advised you to do over an hour ago in my first comment?  Your answer is either contained within the text of one of those answers, or in the linked documents.  Please don't mistake SO for a help-desk.  If you want to get something out of it, you need to put effort in.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45346/discussion-between-yuvraj-kakkar-and-andrew-thompson)

Comment: I realize that message was probably prompted by the site, but I intensely dislike (and won't) 'chat'.  Put further comments here if you would like to get more attention from me.